# Better way to change pandas date format to remove leading zeros?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, leading-zero

DataFrame look like:

```
       OPENED
0  2004-07-28
1  2010-03-02
2  2005-10-26
3  2006-06-30
4  2012-09-21
```

I converted them to my desired format successfully but it seems very inefficient.

```
   OPENED
0   40728
1  100302
2   51026
3   60630
4  120921
```

The code that I used for the date conversion is:

```
df['OPENED'] = pd.to_datetime(df.OPENED, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['OPENED'] = df['OPENED'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%y%m%d'))
df['OPENED'] = df['OPENED'].apply(lambda i: str(i))
df['OPENED'] = df['OPENED'].apply(lambda s: s.lstrip("0"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), then remove first 2 chars by `str[2:]` and last remove leading `0` by [`str.lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
print (type(df.ix[0,'OPENED']))
<class 'str'>
print (df.OPENED.dtype)
object

print (df.OPENED.str.replace('-','').str[2:].str.lstrip('0'))
0     40728
1    100302
2     51026
3     60630
4    120921
Name: OPENED, dtype: object
```

If dtype is already `datetime` use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and [`str.lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
print (type(df.ix[0,'OPENED']))
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
print (df.OPENED.dtype)
datetime64[ns]

print (df.OPENED.dt.strftime('%y%m%d').str.lstrip('0'))
0     40728
1    100302
2     51026
3     60630
4    120921
Name: OPENED, dtype: object
```

Thank you [`Jon Clements`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39017748/better-way-to-change-pandas-date-format-to-remove-leading-zeros#comment65386375_39017803) for comment:

```
print (df['OPENED'].apply(lambda L: '{0}{1:%m%d}'.format(L.year % 100, L)))
0     40728
1    100302
2     51026
3     60630
4    120921
Name: OPENED, dtype: object
```

Comment: And just to throw it out there: `df['OPENED'].apply(lambda L: '{0}{1:%m%d}'.format(L.year % 100, L))`

Comment: Thanks guys, exactly what I was looking for :).  Just out of curiosity, what is / are the python concept(s) that you used to to solve this?  I am new and terrible as you could probably tell and I'd like to learn

Comment: @anshanno - do you need explain first or second solution more? Type of data is `string` or `Timestamp` ?

Comment: Well, my date was a string so the first solution was excellent.  I just meant, what concepts / python features do I need to learn to be able to write that on my own :)

Comment: In my solution are used functions for text data processing like [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings), [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str). But pandas use more functions and are similar as text python functions - [summary](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary).

Comment: And how it works: First replace all `-` by empty string, then remove first 2 chars `a= 'abcdef'` and `a[2:]`, see [here](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/). Last need only remove 0 from left side, so use `lstrip`.